# I need to upload images in asp to sql and then view them in asp

Tags: sql, asp-classic

I am relatively new to sql and asp. My problem is that i need to be able to upload a number of image files, mainly jpgs, to a sql database database. 
Then i need to be able to display them as part of a catalogue.
Ive searched around for a while and am struggling to find anything that seems to let me do this.

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do this would be to upload the files to a directory on the web server, then just store the path to the file in the SQL database.

You can store the actual image in the DB using BLOB columns, but it's generally not recommended.

Comment: Plus one on this. I have attempted storing images in the database in applications in the past, and it causes all sorts of issues, especially once you start adding large amounts of images, because the size of the database grows way too fast.

Comment: Thanks, will go down that route